# Google Analytics lowercase filter for Campaign Term did not change my data. Why?

Tags: google-analytics, filtering, case-sensitive, campaigns

Universal Analytics sent a notification "Property XXXX is receiving hits with `utm_term` parameters of the same text but different letter cases" (e.g. MY term, my term, My Term) and proposed to set up a lowercase filter for Campaign Term, which I did.

[image: lowercase filter Campaign Term]

After one week, the `Keyword` column in `Paid Keyword` view keeps showing a couple of lines with mixed cases.

[image]

Moreover, if in the `All Campaigns` you select `Keyword` as a Primary Dimension it shows many more mixed cases words that came from some non-paid campaigns

[image]

I checked actual URLs in BigQuery. All these words that appear in the `Keyword` column do come as `utm_term` parameters.

Why did not Campaign Term lowercase filter change my data?

Comment: Are you only looking at data in the date range from 24hrs after the filter was applied, up to the current date? Filters are not retroactive.

Comment: @BronwynV yes, of course!

Comment: I had to ask :)

Comment: @BronwynV After you asked and received a reply, any answer? :) My guess is that lowercase Campaign Term filter do not use utm_term, but uses what is encrypted in gclid parameter. Since it is related to the Paid Campaigns first. I'll investigate this issue more.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the filter is working. It took 5 days, not 24-48 hours as Google usually says, for it to be effective.
In my original explanation, I made a mistake. I did check the filter one week later after I set it up, but I checked data of 2-3 days after the setup, not after 7 days.

It's more complicated.
I just found an interesting fact.
On Aug 12 I checked Paid Keywords of Aug 5-11. There were 2 lines with upper case. Now I checked the same time period Aug 5-11 -- all Keywords are in lowercase! It means the filter has been slowly working. and GA was showing the current progress

Comment: Thank you for coming back and posting the solution!